# MIgrate to 2.1 to 3.1 .net core issue with Addjson file

Tags: c#, .net, migration, asp.net-core-3.1

I am Trying to migrate my project with Testing framework to 3.1 from 2.1 and could see the below issue in program.cs file while doing the .

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'    TestAutomation.Application.Hosting.WebApi

AND

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0122  'HostingEnvironment' is inaccessible due to its protection level    TestAutomation.Application.Hosting.WebApi

Below is program.cs code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;


using Serilog;
using TestAutomation.Application.Hosting.WebApi.Extensions;

namespace TestAutomation.Application.Hosting.WebApi
{
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal;
    using System.Net;

    public static class Program
    {
        private static readonly CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(BuildConfiguration("appsettings.json"))
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting web host");
               // ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                BuildWebHost(args)
                    .RunAsync(CancellationTokenSource.Token)
                    .GetAwaiter()
                    .GetResult();

                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
                Shutdown();
                return 1;
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                    AddConfigurations(builder, context.HostingEnvironment))
                .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
                    options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseSerilog()
                .Build();

        private static void AddConfigurations(IConfigurationBuilder builder, IWebHostEnvironment environment) =>
            builder
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile(environment, "appsettings", false, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        private static IConfiguration BuildConfiguration(string name) =>
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile(CreateCurrentEnvironment(), name, false)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

        public static void Shutdown() =>
            CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        public static IWebHostEnvironment CreateCurrentEnvironment() =>
            new HostingEnvironment
            {
               // WebRootPath = string.Empty,
                WebRootFileProvider = null,
                ContentRootFileProvider = null,
                ContentRootPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                ApplicationName = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name,
                EnvironmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")
            };

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG208.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.